# How can I add a description to a rake task after it has been defined?

Tags: ruby, rake

A typical rake task definition looks like this:

```
desc "Set the environment value for the database"
task "environment:set" => [:environment, :load_config] do
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata.create_table
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata[:environment] = ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_environment
end
```

But what if it doesn't have the `desc`, and I want to add it later on in the runtime, after the file with the task definitions has executed. Something like `desc "this is the documentation", task: :taskname`. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like the approach here achieves overriding the desc and behavior: http://metaskills.net/2010/05/26/the-alias-method-chain-of-rake-override-rake-task/

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is a rather old question, I'm posting my answer for anyone landing here from a Google search.

A task can be mentioned multiple times, and a `desc` before it will add (not replace) the given description to it every time. There are also methods on the task object we can use to the same effect:

```rb
# Rakefile

desc 'Foo 1'
task :foo

desc 'Foo 2'
task :foo

task(:foo).add_description 'Foo 3'
task(:foo).comment = 'Foo 4'
```

```bash
rake -T
# => rake foo  # Foo 1 / Foo 2 / Foo 3 / Foo 4
```

The notion "after a task has executed" is a little bit unclear whether it means executing the task definition or the task body. The latter is up to Rake's dependency and recency resolution so a task body may never be executed.

Regardless, technically, we can call `#add_description` and `#comment=` at any time, *even in the task body*. Although I can't think of a practical effect to this, as descriptions are only shown with `rake -T` and `rake -D` which do not execute any tasks.

```rb
task :foo do |t|
  # ...
  t.add_description 'executed' # technically possible, but to what avail?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a desc after the fact as long as it's directly above the "task" method.

The link to the Github repo is broken, but if you look [at the source here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint/RubyLint%2FRakeTask:description), you can see that desc is just appending a string when 
`rake -T` is called.

Comment: By "after the fact" I mean "further down in the code". So, it can't be directly above the `task` method.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. No. The desc method is linked to the next task method.  Putting the desc method after the task results in the desc being assigned to the next task, or not at all if it's at the end of the rakefile. Having two desc methods results in the latter one over-riding the first. Out of curiosity, why can't you put it before the task method? There might be some sort of hack, but that's beyond my scope.

Comment: Your "after the fact" comment needs to be in your question as if it'd always been there. Add it so everyone else understands what you're talking about. (Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can tell what changed.) You should explain why you don't want it above the task where it's supposed to go.